# What are some real world applications that generate large numbers of records in a database every day and what are those metrics?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, performance, storage, query-performance

I'm trying to get some perspective in today's day and age what is considered a large amount of data or large number of records generated in a day and what real world applications are doing that. I would guess large banks have to be generating many records every day in their systems, and I wonder just how many this actually is, hundreds of thousands, millions, hundreds of millions, etc?

How do they typically manage this much data every day from a data storage, query performance, and maintenance perspective?...how do they not run out of primary key values if they aren't using something like a GUID?

Comment: "*how do they not run out of primary key values*" if you use an Oracle sequence and need 10000 sequence values per second 24/7 then you can sustain that rate for 31709791983764586 years without running out of values. For Postgres or SQL Server using a "bigint" it's a bit shorter: you run out of values in 29247120 years  When using an `integer` sequence this would be exhausted in 68 years

Comment: Yea I wrote this question up quickly while at work. I should have specified I meant in the context of MS SQL. Thanks for your reply though. I figured a BIGINT would run out a lot quicker but I didn't do the math.

Comment: [One petabyte of data every day.](https://home.cern/about/computing)

Answer (score 2):

Trading. I was part of a DWH team for a larger trading outfit and we generated 110 million update rows per day on existing contracts. Requirement to keep them for years.

Now I dabble in the field, and my validation systems have peaks of around 500 million rows per day, but we only keep those for a week or so.

> how do they not run out of primary key values if they aren't using something 
>   like a GUID?

Composite keys. Contract, date, update number. Stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked at a place where our billing data ranged from 80GB to 200GB or so every month. Every few days new bills were generated and old bills archived to another server. The original schema was based on int values for the PK and that was a big mistake even though it was best practices at the time. It was a huge project to change it to bigint and change code to use negative numbers as well.

Fast storage was nice. I also figured out that it was faster to run index maintenance daily than once a week. Daily it would run for 15 minutes or so and not cause many problems. If run weekly then it took hours and sometimes impacted people serving customers on weekends.